# Center CCLabel exactly in the center of a CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to add a label on top of a CCSprite, and no matter what size the text on the label is it should be centered exactly in the middle / center of the sprite.

Heres my code now:

```
self.background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"LetterBrick.png"];
    self.background.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:self.background];
    _letterLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:self.letter fontName:@"ChunkFive" fontSize:35];    
    [self addChild:_letterLabel];
```

and the output:

[image]
I just want it a little bit lower hehe.

As you can see the x position is fine, but the y position is too high. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCLabel's anchorPoint is (0.5f, 0.5f) by default. If you want it to be right in the center of it's parent (your sprite with background, in this case), just set label's position to sprite's center

```
CGPoint backSize = background.contentSize;
[label setPosition:ccp(backSize.width / 2, backSize.height / 2)];
```

or equal to it

```
[label setPosition:ccpMult( ccpFromSize(background.contentSize), 0.5f )];
```

Comment: `self.background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"LetterBrick.png"];
    [self addChild:self.background];
    _letterLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:self.letter fontName:@"ChunkFive" fontSize:35.0f];
    CGSize backSize = self.background.contentSize;
    _background.position = ccp(backSize.width/2, backSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:_letterLabel];`                 Didn't work :(

Comment: Try to not post code in comments. It is rather hard to read it. Anyway, as i see, you set position to background, not to your label. Oh, sorry, just now noticed, that you don't add your label to your background, but both of them has the same parent. As for me, it is not comfortable. You can create object for letter, that will contain background and label. By default this label will be empty, but you can add method setLetter to be able to change it. It will make code clearer

Comment: Well with the new code i managed to get the label on the sprite where the x position is okay, but the y is a little off. The bottom of the label is in the middle though.. (And that's not how it is supposed to be hehe) - I actually want it exactly the same way as wordfeud letters are. (in the middle)

Comment: Make sure that your background sprite has no transparent parts(it can cause offset when you calculate position from contentSize).

Comment: I figured out the font was corrupted. It didn't have a top padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
_letterLabel.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f,0.5f);
_letterLabel.position = ccp(sprite.position.x, sprite.position.y);
```